# AFNetworking setImageWithURL - get height of returned image?

Tags: iphone, ios, afnetworking, heightforrowatindexpath

I'm looking to set the image within a custom tableviewcell and use the height of the returned image within the heightForRowAtIndexPath method.

Is there anyway to get this returned data into the heightForRowAtIndexPath method?
Currently I'm using a local dictionary and setting it as per below:

```
   NSURLRequest* urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:recent.show.showImage] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad timeoutInterval:30];


   [cell.imageView setImageWithURLRequest:urlRequest placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon"] success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {

       NSNumber *imageHeight = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithFloat:image.size.height];
       NSString *indexString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.row];
       [self.returnedImages setValue:imageHeight forKey:indexString];
       [imageHeight release];

   } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

   }];
```

any pointers on a more efficient approach greatly appreciated.

Cheers
Nik

Comment: Is the current scheme not performant?  An interesting question (I don't know the answer) is whether `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is called before or after `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`.  In other words, is your dictionary entry available when the height requested?

Comment: I'm not sure you can guarantee the order in which those methods are called - they may well be asynchronous.

Comment: Thanks. Currently I'm calling set image in both cell at index and height at index methods. Seems to be ok. Whichever one gets called first doesn't matter as on subsequent call the cache is used.

Answer (score 1):

The way you're currently doing this in a NSDictionary is appropriate. Although to make sure it updates as quickly as possible you could add `[self.tableView reloadData]` to your success block, since then it will immediately refresh your tableview with the updated data. Even better you could use the `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` and pass it just the index path of the newly downloaded UIImage so it won't refresh the entire tableview.

[Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)